# Application Ready for upload and in-app purchases

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have a live iOS app. on the store.

I created a new version and I had the state "Ready for Upload".

After that I added a new in-app purchases and I got those state "Approved".

Does that mean all I have to do now is to upload my IPA throw the Application Loader and those in-app purchases will be available on that new version.

Usually, I remember before proceed with the step "Ready to upload binary" I should attach those new purchases to that version. Is that right? Am I remembering well?

Or, I have to self reject the new binary after uploading it throw application loader and then attach purchases and proceed again with ready to upload binary then re-upload. because rejecting it is the only way to get a step backward?

Any ideas?

What we can get from this apple doc "Approved" state means?

> Apple has approved your In-App Purchase to go live on the App Store
>   with its associated app. For this status to appear, the In-App
>   Purchase must be cleared for sale in iTunes Connect. If it is not
>   cleared for sale, the status appears as “Developer Removed from Sale.”
>   If the product is being released with an app version, the product
>   won’t have an Approved status until the app is approved.

Comment: this was a little confusing but it sounds to me like your new in-app purchases are already approved so they should appear in the already-released version of your app. And if you get a new version of your app approved, they will appear in it also. There's no "coupling" between approval of the purchase items and approval of a new app version, necessarily/

Comment: do you remember if we attach the purchases to the new version before we proceed with ready to upload binary? because, I don't want to wait for a whole week while apple review the app. and then realise that purchases are not available.

Comment: I think you can submit the purchases independently of the app binary, before or after. It's just that purchases automatically get held up and batched with your app for the *first* version of your app that supports in-app purchase. I recently submitted some purchases and a new app version on the same day, and they got approved independently at different times.

Comment: @hasan Did you figure out the answer? I remember what you are saying too and now I can't find this option for adding my new iAPs?

Comment: Yes I got an answer. If your app is live and already have old purchases. then don't worry about it. any new added purchases will automatically is going to be released with the new version. is this answer is good enough for you?